# AWS pre-signed s3 url is often redirecting to https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the below ***NodeJS*** code snippet to store a pdf at AWS s3 and to return a pre signed URL to the front end so that the file can be downloaded by the user.

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Env } from "@adasd/common";
import logger from "./logger";

const S3 = new AWS.S3();
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: "us-east-1" });

export async function streamDocumentToS3(stream: any, fileName: string, Bucket: string, module: string): Promise<any> {
    const environment = Env.getEnv().toLowerCase();
    const Key = `${module}/${environment}/${fileName}`;
    const bucketParams = {
        Bucket,
        Key,
        Body: stream,
    };
    await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams));
    const signedUrl = await getDocumentURL(Bucket, Key);
    logger.info(`#Checklist s3 signed URL:: ${signedUrl}`);
    return signedUrl;
}

export function getDocumentURL(Bucket: string, Key: string) {
    return S3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
        Bucket,
        Key,
        Expires: 5 * 60 //5 minutes default
    });
}
```

**For the first time after each deployment** in the Linux server, the pre signed URL is redirecting to https://aws.amazon.com/s3/ as shown in the below screenshot, even if the generated pre signed URL is valid. This is not happening in development environment. What could be the cause?

[image]